# Why did Shazam break this object?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, shazam-2019

In *Shazam!* (2019), we see Shazam break

> the wizard’s staff after transforming his foster brothers and sisters.

Why did he do so? Doesn’t this have dire consequences for future generations in terms of replacements?

Comment: i would add that even in this generation there are supposed to be 7 Shazams

Answer (score 3):

He was trying to remove any possibility of Sivana gaining the power of Shazam. The staff was needed to transfer the power, so by breaking it there is no way for him to transfer it anymore.

It might have consequences for passing on the power of Shazam, or it might not. The wizards had to have worked out how to transfer their power themselves so Shazam and co. might be able to do the same. If nothing else, they could remain in Shazam form forever and be effectively immortal.

Comment: Also, that’s exactly how a 14year old would think. Break the staff and Sivana would lose his connection to it. A matured adult would have thought of something more logical but a kid cannot.

Comment: Immortal? Wasn't the wizard going to die?

Answer (score 3):

> Why did Shazam break this object?

According to Shazam himself in *Shazam! Fury of the Gods* (2023) (emphasis mine):

> **Shazam:** I mean, I did break it in half and then throw it away. So, that's probably where the journey started.
> […]
> And then **I had to break it in half so Sivana didn't do super bad-guy stuff with it**, okay?
> **Mary:** You broke the staff, meaning you broke the barrier between worlds.

---

> Doesn’t this have dire consequences for future generations in terms of replacements?

**Yes**, especially since there’s no replacement for it. In *Shazam! Fury of the Gods* (2023), it was revealed that Shazam’s breaking of the staff in *Shazam!* (2019) was a careless mistake that enabled the antagonists to enact their plan. Breaking it in half broke the barriers between the human realm and the god realm and allowed Atlas’ daughters to take the staff.

The staff was where Atlas (the Titan god) stored all supernatural power. A council of human wizards later stole the staff from Atlas. They used it to take away his powers and those of other gods, and sealed the god realm in a magical sphere. The staff contains the power of the gods, and it was described by Eugene Choi, one of Billy’s foster siblings who also gained Shazam’s powers, as “a battery for magic.” Atlas’ daughters were able to use the staff to depower Billy’s foster siblings.